# Not found LG Optimus L3 E400f ???????????? no permissions to test apps android

Tags: android, linux, lg

Helllo I'm try to test the applications android in the mobile LG Optimus L3 E400f, but not works. This is the things that I do to try to solve the mistake.

1.identify the device ID  then I type lsusb and this show :

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1004:61fc LG Electronics, Inc.
```

2.Edit the file  **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**  and add the next things:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
```

3.Restar my computer

4.run the adb and find the devices, this is the moment when I give the mistake(again):

```
 ./adb devices
```

This show:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

(Always my mobile  has been on development mode).

How to fix my trouble?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ATTR{idVendor` instead of `SYSFS`

Like so:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"`

and if that doesn't work put `GROUP="plugdev"` at the end of the line.

Comment: It's works perfectly with `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"`. what is the difference between the both ways?.  @ruffner Thank you!.

Comment: I stumbled on this problem a while ago with a custom made usb device, if memory serves it has to do with the version of udev thats running. I think the `SYSFS` tag is outdated perhaps.